# Python flask url not working for parameters in given in postman

Tags: python, flask, postman

I am trying to create a python flask API for the prediction app in the code there are two functions one is get_location_name which works fine in postman but the other get_estimated_price() is not working.
it is said that I have to give parameters in the body which I have given in the form data. but still facing this issue. I am not able to understand what to do now

below is the code

postman image
[error on post](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sAUZJ.png)

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
import util
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/get_location_names')
def get_location_names():
    response = jsonify({
    'locations': util.get_location_names()})
    response.headers.add('Access-Control- 
    Allow-Origin', '*')

    return response
@app.route('/get_estimated_price', methods = 
['POST'])
def get_estimated_price():
    total_sqft = 
    float(request.form['total_sqft'])
    location = request.form['location']
    bhk = int(request.form['bhk'])
    bath = int(request.form['bath'])

    response = jsonify({
    'estimated_price':util.get_estimated_price(location,total_sqft,bhk,bath)
    })

    response.headers.add('Access-Control-Origin','*')

    return response

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("starting Python Flask Server for Home Price Prediction....")
    util.load_saved_Artifacts()
    app.run()
```

[GET request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aOKn.png)

Comment: Please fix your indentation. In python the indentation significantly effects what code does, so it's impossible to tell what you are doing without the correct indentation.

Comment: fixed the indentation of code

Answer (score 0):

You have added the params in the body section of the request. Switch to the params tab. When you have successfully added the params they will appear in the URL request.

E.g when adding params correctly,

https://123.12.1/get_price?param1=3?param2=a

Hope this helps.